# Assigning Same Values to RichTextBox Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a RichTextBox.  I am extracting the content and assigning to the same RichTextBox, (this is for realitime texteditor),  The RichTextBox is not accepting more than 1 character after i give a newline.  I tested by assigning the values to another RichTextBox, if works fine.  Can someone look into the below code?

```
private void richTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = richTextEditor.Text;
    string strMod = "";
    richTextEditor.Clear();

    if (str.Contains('\n'))
    {
        string[] strArr = str.Split('\n');

        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Count(); i++)
        {
            strMod += strArr[i];
            strMod += Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        strMod = str;
    }

    richTextEditor.AppendText(strMod);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  If so, what is it?  Also, you should really consider using a `StringBuilder` rather than concatenating strings.

Comment: Why are you doing this? You're replacing '\n' with NewLine at each keypress. That's not a good idea, even for those rare cases where NewLine will not be '\n'. If you need to make sure all new lines are properly separated (something else which can be debated), you should do it afterwards, not during the editing.

Comment: Another disadvantage of this approach (and even with Hans' answer) is that the cursor will jump to the end after each text change. Remembering where the cursor was, where it should be, etc, will be a lot of trouble. Instead, how about you tell us why you need to do this?

Comment: Furthermore, it appears that RichTextBox could very well decide not to carry carriage returns (str never has a carriage return in my case, even though strMod has them). So the whole process could very well be pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a NewLine to the last line.  Fix:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++) {
        strMod += strArr[i];
        if (i < strArr.Length - 1) strMod += Environment.NewLine;
    }
```

Or just plain:

```
    strMod = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, strArr);
```

Also beware that this code causes the TextChanged event to fire again.  You are getting away with it right now because you are not actually changing anything.  But that luck will run out soon.  Use a bool flag to prevent the re-entrancy from causing trouble:

```
    private bool changingText = false;

    private void richTextEditor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (changingText) return;
        changingText = true;
        try {
            // etc...
        }
        finally {
            changingText = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After the first new line, you're adding an extra new line here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Count(); i++)
{
    strMod += strArr[i];
    strMod += Environment.NewLine;
}
```

So if I enter:

```
    Text
    M
```

I will get

```
    Text
    M
```

You're adding an extra line after the last entry on text change, meaning that any new character really does trigger a split and adds a new line.

See my comment. Why are you doing this at all? What are you trying to accomplish?

---

EDIT:

There is a simpler way, using Hans Passant's bool flag:

```
private bool changingText = false;

private void richTextEditor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (changingText) return;
    changingText = true;

    try
    {
        string str = richTextEditor.Text.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
        richTextEditor.Clear();
        richTextEditor.AppendText(str);
    }
    finally
    {
        changingText = false;
    }
}
```

However, my previous remarks remain: this is essentially an ill-placed operation, and it forces the caret to the end at every change.